# StarTeam: EOL format for Binary files like Images

Tags: eol, starteam, end-of-line

I have binary files in my StarTeam Projects like images with extension (*.gif, *.bmp).
I have check-in them in StarTeam using EOL format Windows (CRLF).
But when I checkout them, they are Unix EOL format (LF).

So I wanted to change the EOL of these files from LF to CRLF.
I right-click on a file with .gif extension, and select Properties...
But in the General tab, I find the field "EOL check-out format" is disabled so that I cannot change it.

What should I do so that these files are always checked out as CRLF?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that an EOL format makes sense for binary files.  It only makes sense for Text files.  Binary files are identical in any platform, as EOL is not relevant to such a format.